# Mongo collection.update not removing element even though it returns 1 as the number of objects updated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to remove the second section let's say from the object below. I know the `section_id` of the `section` object that I want to remove and the code below returns 1 as if 1 record was removed, but no `section` objects are actually removed.

What am i doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Example object

```
{
  _id: 'asdfjklsfo',
  name: 'My name',
  sections: [
    {
      section_id: 'asdflasdf', <-- This is an actual mongo ObjectID
      title: 'My title'
    },
    {
      section_id: 'asdflnmasdf', <-- This is an actual mongo ObjectID
      title: 'Second title'
    }
  ]
}
```

Update snippet

```
var collection = db.get('notes');
collection.update(
        { _id: id },
        { $pull: { sections: {section_id : section_id}}},

        function(err, num_modified) {

            // If it failed, return error
            if (err) {
                res.send("There was a problem deleting that note from the database.");
            } else {
                console.log(num_modified); <-- this is 1
                console.log('were in delete success');
                res.send(204);
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Have you tried the same statement in the console? Is it working there?

Comment: I tried this `collection.update({ _id: 'myid' }, { $pull: { sections: {section_id : 'mysectionid'}}},` and it didn't remove anything. I had to change it to this for it to work int he mongo console: `collection.update({ _id: ObjectId("myid") }, { $pull: { sections: {section_id : ObjectId("mysectionid")}}},`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had to do `collection.id(section_id)` like this:

```
collection.update(
        { _id: id },
        { $pull: { sections: {section_id : collection.id(section_id)}}},

        function(err, num_modified) {

            // If it failed, return error
            if (err) {
                res.send("There was a problem deleting that note from the database.");
            } else {
                console.log(num_modified); <-- this is 1
                console.log('were in delete success');
                res.send(204);
            }
        }
    );
```

Since i'm using the Monk library, I got it from this: https://github.com/LearnBoost/monk#casting